# Postfix sends from localhost using mail but does not relay mails from local clients

Tags: email, postfix

For a couple of days I am trying to configure Postfix/Dovecot, I did my best to follow the guides, I can receive mail but cannot send mail from other mail clients than localhost.

Here is a syslog line regarding to a try from a mail-client from the LAN:

```
Mar 28 12:37:38 mail postfix/smtpd[12524]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ***.ru[***.***.64.243]: 454 4.7.1 <***@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<***@mymail.server> to=<***@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[***.16.98.44]>
```

Sending mail from the localhost via mail command:

> mail ***@gmail.com

This works as expected.

I don't know where to go further, any suggestions/help would be very appreciated.

My main.cf file looks like:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package     for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.myserver.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = myserver.com
mydestination = myserver.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 5.9.145.38/32
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = 
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

Comment: Try separating the options in `smtpd_relay_restrictions` with commas.

Comment: Tried - no luck. Actually I got some feedback from postfix while I played with the options - postfix recognizes them...

Answer (score 1):

Postfix allows relaying emails from the localhost via mail command because of:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 5.9.145.38/32
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```

Because your other email-clients are from the LAN, but these LAN IP addresses are not part of `mynetworks`, postfix prohibits relaying email. You need to add all local IP addresses, you wish to permit sending emails using your mail server as a relay, to mynetworks. I.e. if your LAN is `192.168.1.x` you need to add

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 5.9.145.38/32 192.168.1.0/24
```

With this configuraion all clients with IP addresses like 192.168.1.x may relay emails using your server.